# Ruby on Rails failed to add a new data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making simple CRUD and the current goal is to add data. However, I found that I can't add any data, and the terminal log also shows "[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do", which means there is no error message.

According to my design in the controller, the new data must have failed, so I stopped at new.html.erb. I'm guessing it has something to do with the model's relationship.

This is model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :recipes, through: :reviews
end
```

This is the model Recipe

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is model Review

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

This is the RecipeController

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all  
  end

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new  
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipes_path, notice: "Successful!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :money)
  end
end
```

this is the web page

```
<h1>Add New One</h1>

<%= form_for(@recipe) do |r| %>
  <%= r.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= r.text_field :title%>

  <%= r.label :money, "Budget" %>
  <%= r.text_field :money %>

  <%= r.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back to list", recipes_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first add a callback to ensure that only signed in users can create recipes (unless you actually want to let anomynous users create/update/delete recipies).

For example with Devise you would use its `authenticate_user!` helper which will bail and redirect to the sign in path if the user is not authenticated:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  # ...
end
```

If you're reinventing the authentication wheel you should create a similiar method which is used to prevent access.

You would then initialize the resource off the current user:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]

  def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipes_path, notice: "Successful!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here I am assuming that you have a `current_user` method which will retrieve the user based on an id stored the session.

Since you have an indirect assocation this will create a row in the `reviews` table with the users id and the recipe id as the record in the recipies table.

You also want to [display the validation errors](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) in the form so that the user gets feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right that it is a validation error related to the belongs_to relationship. You should display validation errors for your form as described here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#validations-and-displaying-error-messages

Comment: If I remove ```belongs_to :user``` in the model recipe it works fine, does that mean I need to add ```current_user```?

Comment: I'd say probably yes, but check what the validation errors say